# Error con la media query CSS3 no se adapta?

Tags: css3, mediaqueries

Buenas tengo este siguiente codigo :

```css
@media screen and (max-width:100px){
    #yo {
        border:1px solid green;
      }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/7.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  
<section>   
   <div class="container">
      <h4 >titulo</h4>       
       <h5 >My name is</h5>
       <h6>My profesional</h6>
       <hr style="border-bottom:1px solid red; width: 10%;">

       <img id="yo" class="img-fluid" src="https://scontent.fhmo1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/23131644_154606561942762_3784176640472935786_n.jpg?oh=5e8ff9723d95c67188f3eb81ace919e5&oe=5AD32247" width="200" height="200">
       <p style=" float:right;width:70%;">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
         tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
         quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
         consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
         cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
         proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
       </p>
   </div>
 </section>
```

como ven uso una @media para aplicarle un border verde(el id es una img,entiendo que no se recomienda usa id en css pero solamente es una preuba)

Y el framework que uso es materialize , en el código están todas las recursos del proyecto.

El tutorial para hacer la media lo encontre en mzo dev:
[Media - tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Alguien sabe donde tengo el error?

Comment: No veo ningún error. Debería funcionarte. Ten en cuenta que únicamente te mostrará el borde verde alrededor de la imagen si la ventana en la que se encuentra tiene un ancho menor de 100 píxels. Tendrás que hacer la ventana muy pequeña para poder ver el efecto, pero por lo demás no hay ningún problema en tu código.

Comment: lose no tengo ningun error pero no me funciona :/ en opera ni en chrome y menos en internet exploret

Comment: He modificado tu pregunta para poder ejecutar el código. Si aumentas el ancho de la media query acabará mostrándose el borde. Dependerá de la resolución de tu monitor, a mí con 700px me muestra el borde.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me estaba pasando exactamente lo mismo, el css estaba perfecto y mi formulario no se adaptaba, el problema era que no tenia la etiqueta meta viewport.

> Usa esta etiqueta meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```

> Todo lo demas esta bien.